# Powershell Bool returns Array

Tags: powershell

I'm tryng to return $true or $false from a function, and I get an array .
If I remove the listBox messages it works as expected. Does anyone know why?

```
function TestEmptyFields()
{
  $empty= $false

  $listBox1.Items.Add("Testing fields")

  if ($txtPrtName.get_text()-eq "")
  {
    $listBox1.Items.Add("Empty name")
    $empty= $true
  }
  elseif ($txtPrtIP.get_text() -eq "")
  {
    $listBox1.Items.Add("Empty Ip")
    $empty= $true
  } 
  else 
  {
    $empty= $false
  }

  $listBox1.Items.Add($txtPrtName.get_text())
  $listBox1.Items.Add($txtPrtIP.get_text())

  return $empty
}
```

But it works fine like this:

```
function TestEmptyFields()
{
  if($txtPrtName.get_text()-eq "")
  {
    return $true
  }
  elseif ($txtPrtIP.get_text() -eq "")
  {
    return $true
  }
  else
  {
    return $false
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try returning the value earlier? i.e. not writing `$empty= $true` but directly `return $true` instead? Apart from that it is not that easy to help you debug this if we do not have the parts where `$txtPrtName`, `$txtPrtIP` and `$listBox1` get assigned/declared. I would also recommend you not to process global variables in a function but make them parameters of that function.

Comment: thanks , i've tryed and it's the same behavior.

Comment: But it works fine like this :

Comment: function TestEmptyFields()
 {
 
   if($txtPrtName.get_text()-eq "")
   {   
   
   return $true
   
   }elseif($txtPrtIP.get_text() -eq "")
   {
   
   return $true
    
   }else{
   
   return $false
   }    

 }

Comment: can you include the code that sets up the variables that you are testing in your function? or make them parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In powershell `return $empty` is functionally equivalent to `$empty ; return` -- that behavior was implemented to make things easier for people with a background in C-style languages, but you're actually returning more than you think!  The listboxes return content as well.  In fact, anything that isn't assigned to a variable or otherwise has its output nullified will reach the output stream. To fix this, try casting listbox to `[void]` like so:

```
[void] $listBox1.Items.Add("Testing fields")
```

It probably wouldn't hurt to review this [TechNet guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730949.aspx) on proper usage of Listboxes in the context of a form, either.

Comment: Plug, if you don't mind - http://stacktoheap.com/blog/2013/06/15/things-that-trip-newbies-in-powershell-pipeline-output/

Comment: "anything that isn't assigned to a variable or otherwise has its output nullified will reach the output stream". 
Is this concept a Microsoft design decision for some known reason? It seems to me more an annoyance, prone to develop buggy functions.